# how to set validation rules to permit document creation only if documents with the same fields are not present with Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to use Cloud Firestore with my android app. 
So i am storing 3-4 fields . So i ll give an example with cars collection.
There is a "cars" collection.documents of the cars collection have fields: 
manufacturer,model,top speed.

I am adding the data with android with code as below :

```
dManufacturer = "Hyundai"
dModel = "Kona"
dTopSpeed ="150"
Map<String, Object> car = new HashMap<>();
car.put("manufacturer", dManufacturer);
car.put("model", dModel);
car.put("top_speed",dTopSpeed);


db.collection(cars")
.add(car)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
 Log.d("firebaseab", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
 }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
 @Override
 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
 Log.w("firebaseab", "Error adding document", e);
 }
});
```

So any user using my app should be able to add only 1 car document and that document if has all field values similar to a document in the collection then the data should not be added.

I'll tell what options i have tried and am thinking of  but please help with telling me what is the best way to achieve this and how to achieve this .

So i was thinking of achieving this with creating validation security rules to save query quota so as to keep within the free plan as much as possible but i am not understanding how it works so i keep getting errors or permission denied.

the ways i tried :

1) i tried to write a rule for "!=" match with documents in the collection to the one in create request that i do from android as above but it  was giving me errors. i hav not yet perfectly understood  what is happening. the rule is like :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    // match /{document=**} {
    //   //allow create: if document != request.resource.data;
    //   allow create: if document.manufacturer == "Google";
    // }
    match /cars/{car} {
      allow create : if request.resource.data.manufacturer != resource.data.manufacturer
                    && request.resource.data.model != resource.data.model
                    && request.resource.data.topSpeed != resource.data.topSpeed;

    }
  }
}
```

But the above gave error and was not working.

Dont know how to use the !exists to compare in a document with same field values exists or not . They can have different document id's but if values of fields are same then i dont want to add another document with the same field values.

The ways that i am thinking but dont know which is correct or how to implement:

1) Would creating a compound index with all the values that i need to match for in there? But how do i write the security rules so that i dont have to check or perform get queries from my code.

2) Should i create document id as compund index (but how should i do that and how to write security validation rules then)

3) Should i create document id from client side in format "manufacturer_model_topspeed" . So it would be according to my example - 
"Hyundai_Kona_150". Will this help to maintain uniqueness. If it will then when a document with same document id is entered then the permission would be denied . THen how should i handle it at client. Can i send a particular message or value from cloud firestore depicting this particular creation denied event?

4) Should i use Device.Id in android as document id to match to a particular device so if the user has added a document then he cant add more.But this could create duplication of document field data.I am asking this for how to write security rules so that a person who has already written a document cant write again.

5) I also want to know if a way is found to reject duplicate data then how to recieve that rejection in android to let me know that the rejection is not an unhandled error so i can save on device to not contact firestore in future.

Is there any other better way to approach this problem ...please tell.i can even use a bit of client side code to use where clause etc but i want to minimize the read quota. How to do this with minimum read/write quota used.  I am beginner with cloud firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security rules cannot query the database. So there is no way to have your security rules search across the database for a document with the same values for those fields.

What security rules *can* do is check the values of a specific document, or for the existence of a specific document. In both cases you must know the full path of the document, including the ID of the document in question.

So what you could do is create an additional collection, where the key/ID of each document is a concatenation of all the field values that you want to be unique. Then your security rules could check if a document already exists in this secondary collection (often called an "index"), and disallow the write if it does.

Alternatively, you can create a Cloud Function that performs the create of documents. In your Cloud Functions code you can query the database, and only create the document of no conflict exists. When you use this approach, you can still let the app directly read from the database, and perform updates.

Comment: so just to be clear a few questions:  1) why cant i create (concatenation of field values ) as document id for the main collection which has all field values... 2) if i create another collection with the document id's as (concatenated unique field values)  then would that collection have any fields or just a document id....

Comment: 3) I dont want to authenticate the user because i only need certain field values from the user but only once and only if the data is not duplicate ...I also only want the data per device once ...so if the user deletes the app, reinstalls etc then i dont want that user the ability to add document after the first time of doing so. I also want to prevent malicious users who have my code somehow from writing into  the firestore database.... so will the json configuration file for firebase in my android app be encrypted? How do i make firestore detect requests coming from apps from play store only?

Comment: 1) would be possible. The main reason for not doing it, is that you're more likely to hit write throughput limits/delays that way. 2) just the document ID. 3) there is no way to limit access to "coming from your app". The reason is that all information to access the database must be in the app, so a malicious user could copy that into their own code. Authentication is required, if you want to be able authorize specific users and not others.